# How to make backgroundimage move in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

For one of the viewcontrollers in my app, I would like a moving background image. How would I go about making this?

Comment: This is too broad. Provide more details. Move direction ? Move time ? There are many things to be considered.

Comment: Are you trying to do a background that moves if you move the cell around the axis?

Comment: It is pretty simple: The backgroundImageView is zoomed in to the left side of the image. The backgroundImageView should then move slowly from left to right of the image and back again just as a cool little feature. This happens independent of the users actions. Please tell me if it is still unclear:)

Comment: No I am not talking about a table cell as I already said in the question. It is a very very common design effect on websites and apps in general. The background image is slowly moving from side to side of a zoomed-in-image to make a nice little effect.

Comment: Your first comment says: *"if you move the cell around the axis"*. What cell are you talking about? Given all of the comments, you should realize your question is unclear. You should update your question to clarify it. Spreading details through a whole set of comments doesn't help. Update the question.

Comment: That is not my comment rmaddy :)

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. The rest of my comment applies though. You really need to clarify your question.

Comment: my bad, sorry I cause confusion, I was referring to the **cell**phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another `UIView`, add the image inside it and add it as a subview below your view. Than simply animate the frame property of the image. Not sure if this is what you need, but your question is too brief, so is my answer.